# Webpack configuration for ES6

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

- I'm trying to convert my app from CommonJS to ES6 syntax.
- The app has webpack.
- My current `webpack.config.js` is

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
    library: "$",
    libraryTarget: "umd",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
  mode: "development",
};
```

- And my `package.json` has:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
  }
```

- my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

In order for my app to use ES6, do I also need to change my `webpack.config.js` file from commonJS syntax to ES6 syntax - to change `require` to `import` and `module.exports` to named export or default export?

I thought I would need to but after researched a bit, I feel like I don't need to because Webpack will use `babel-loader` to transpile ES6 code to ES5.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are just transpiling away the es modules with babel then you can leave webpack as cjs. If you want to write and build es modules, then webpack also would need to use import/export otherwise node will throw an error.